# Following line of R shiny code not working as expected

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have the following line in my code:

```r
matching_row_index <- which(apply(df1, 1, identical, row_df))
```

Here, `row_df` is a dataframe with only one row. `df1` is another dataframe with many rows and exact same columns as `row_df`. I wish to find the index of that row in `df1`, which matches with the single row of `row_df`. This value of the index is to be given to `matching_row_index`. However, on running the code and using print statements, `print(matching_row_index)` gives output `integer(0)`. Also other functionality in the app which depends on `mathing_row_index` is not working as expected. `print(row_df)` gave correct output as expected, so apparently `row_df` is fine.

Can someone please correct this line of code or explain what is causing the bug?

Comment: `identical` may provide a false-alarm if there are any attributes or minor class differences; for instance, if at any point an integer was converted to a numeric (even if innocently), `identical(1, 1L)` is false despite being effectively equivalent. I've often used `all.equal(..., check.attibutes=FALSE)` (it would be true in the `1`-v-`1L` comparison above). When `which(.)` returns `integer(0)`, it's a clear signal that _something_ is different, even minutely (c.f., see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272).

Comment: Also, with [`all.equal`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html), see its `tolerance=` argument, it might be useful here.

Comment: As for your mention of [tag:shiny], I believe it to be a red herring: shiny is not going to change or affect values, so what is "not matching" within the shiny app is almost certainly to be "not matching" on the R console.

Answer (score 0):

***Guessing.***

`apply` converts its `data.frame` argument to a `matrix`, *always*. This means that if `row_df` is still a frame, then at best `identical` will fail solely due to the class difference. Even if `df1` contains no strings (which would result in all columns being converted to string), if some columns are `numeric` and some `integer`, then *all* columns will be converted to `numeric`, which is clearly going to be "not `identical`".

Even further: the argument being passed to your call of `identical` *is a vector*, not a frame.

The step needed here is to compare the components without R's implicit casting, which means we need to avoid `apply`.

A working example:

```r
mt1 <- mtcars[7,]
which(apply(mtcars, 1, identical, mt1))
# named integer(0)
which(apply(mtcars, 1, function(z) isTRUE(all.equal(z, mt1, check.attributes=FALSE, tolerance=1e-5))))
# named integer(0)
```

None of those work because of casting and vector-vs-frame.

```r
class(mt1)
# [1] "data.frame"

apply(mtcars, 1, function(z) class(z))
#           Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag          Datsun 710      Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet Sportabout             Valiant 
#           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric" 
#          Duster 360           Merc 240D            Merc 230            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE 
#           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric" 
#          Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental   Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128 
#           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric" 
#         Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla       Toyota Corona    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28 
#           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric" 
#    Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2        Lotus Europa      Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino 
#           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric"           "numeric" 
#       Maserati Bora          Volvo 142E 
#           "numeric"           "numeric"
```

So we have some options:

```r
which(sapply(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), function(i) identical(mt1, mtcars[i,])))
# [1] 7

which(sapply(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(mt1, mtcars[i,], check.attributes = FALSE))))
# [1] 7
```

Note that `all.equal` will return `TRUE` if so, but will frustratingly return a *string* (not the intuitive `FALSE`) if something is different. While the string explains what is different, it breaks the singular-class-return-value that one might expect. Ergo we wrap in `isTRUE(.)`.

If you are dealing with high-precision `numeric` data in `df1`, you might consider the use of `tolerance=` in `all.equal`.

There are likely other ways to do row-comparisons.